Is there a way to make WebSockets work in Chrome when proxy is used?
I'm running a socks5 proxy:
--proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:1083" --host-resolver-rules="MAP * ~NOTFOUND, EXCLUDE 127.0.0.1"
but any attempt to use Discord VC fails because it uses wss:// protocol.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It literally explains what the issue is.
